# display the content of a google sheet cell in a web page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have google sheet with a cell containing html code. I would like to know the best way to show this html in a webpage. I have tried with google spreadsheets API and google visualization API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), this can be as simple as:

```
function doGet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Aq4s9w_HxMs7dFVuQ0hDaWl1VVZsQ1RBTVZqM0dHLXc"); // replace with your sheet id
  var html = spreadsheet.getRange("A1").getValue(); // My html is in cell A1
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

Check out the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) Getting Started and Tutorial sections to get an idea of how to develop with Apps Script.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems google aps scripts cannot be exectuted client side from a stand-alone html file. would it be possible to do the same using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can display information from a single cell using the Javascript charts API. Better ways may be available, I am not an expert. To get the snippet below working just add your spreadsheet url and set the range.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        // Add your sheets url and range below
        var spreadsheetUrl = "https://your sheets url here?range=A1";
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
        // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#methods
        // getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="test"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixes my situation. thank you so much! I didn't know much about javascript so i really need full complete code such as this!

Comment: can you do more for me please. I wanted to display multiple cells on the var spreadsheetUrl because i want to display A1 A2 A3 cells at the same time. Can you help me out more? much appreciated.